# $z=100^2-x^2$. Then, how many values of $x,z$ are divisible by $6$?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

> $z=100^2-x^2$. Then, how many values of $x,z$ are divisible by $6$?

My approach:

For $x=1$, $z$ is not divisible by $6$.

For $x=2$, $z$ is divisible by $6$.

For $x=3$, $z$ is not divisible by $6$.

For $x=4$, $z$ is divisible by $6$.

For $x=5$, $z$ is not divisible by $6$.

For $x=6$, $z$ is not divisible by $6$.

For $x=7$, $z$ is divisible by $6$.

For $x=8$, $z$ is divisible by $6$.

I could not identify the pattern in these questions. Also can this problem be solved with a better approach?

Comment: Why wouldn't you start with 100 mod 6 as a starting point? That simplifies this greatly as this would leave you with at most 6 cases to consider.

Comment: @JBKing Please Explain in detail i haven't understood.The Ans is 66

Comment: Did you leave out some pieces? You didn't state in the question whether or not negative values are acceptable for $x$ and $z$ which may be what some of us would presume.

Comment: @Jack At x=4 and At x=7 z is not divisible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a different way to highlight what has already been correctly noted, and to explain why the answer could be $66$, as stated in one of the initial comments by the author of the OP. To avoid confusion, I interpreted the problem as the question of how many values of $x$ lead to a positive $z$ that is divisible by $6$.

Let us start from $z=(100-x)(100+x)$, where the two factors $100-x$ and $100+x$ clearly have the same parity. First, we can observe that the only possibility that $z$ is divisible by $6$ occurs when at least one of these two factors is divisible by $6$. In fact, if any of the two factors is divisible by $3$ and not by $2$, the other factor is also not divisible by $2$, and so $z$ cannot be divisible by $6$.

Then, we can note that $100-x$ is divisible by $6$ only when $x=6j+4$ (with $j$ integer), whereas $100+x$ is divisible by $6$ only when $x=6j+2$.

If we limit the problem to solutions that give positive values of $z$ (although this is not specified in the OP), then $|x|$ can only assume integer values $<100$. It is not difficult to note that there are $16$ positive integers $<100$ of the form $x=6j+4$ (they are $4,10,16,22...94$) and $17$ positive integers $<100$ of the form $x=6j+2$ (they are $2,8,14,20...98$). So, there are $33$ positive integer values of $x$ that lead to a $z$ value that is divisible by $6$.

Lastly, because each of these solutions with a given positive $x$ corresponds to another symmetric solution with $-x$, we have to count other $33$ negative values of $x$. This finally leads to a total of $66$ solutions.

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

$$z=100^2-x^2=(100-x)(100+x)$$

As $(100-x)+(100+x)=200,100\pm x$ have same parity and

if one is divisible by $3,$the other is not

So if $2|z,100\pm x$ must be even

If $3|z,3|(100-x)(100+x)\implies$

either $3|(100-x)\iff x\equiv1\pmod3$

or $3|(100+x)\iff x\equiv-1\pmod3$

Comment: Not understood please explain in detail?.Why  u added (100+x)+(100-x)=200,100+-x.What is 2lz,3lz,3l?

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee I also not understood the solution.Can anybody else explain clearly.I didn't got  $100+-x$.When i put x=0,i got x=200.What does parity mean here.

Comment: @Jack,  $a|b$ means  $a$ divides $b$  Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @justintakro, parity means even or odd. What's ur confusion?

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee When u put x=0,you get 200.Q1 I mean at what value you get $100+-x$.Q2 Can you give an example what this statement mean "if one is divisible by 3,the other is not".

Comment: @justintakro, $$x=0\implies100\pm x=100$$   If $x=3k,$ none is divisible by $3$. If $$x=3k+1,100+x=101+3x\equiv1\pmod3\not\equiv0$$  If $$x=3k+2,100+x=102+3x=3(x+34)\equiv0\pmod3$$

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee When we put x=3k we get (100+3k)(100-3k)=p.j where p=3(k+33)+1 and j=3(-k+33)+1. is it right?How you are confident it is not divisible by 3.I think any number of the form 3K+1 is not divisible by 3.Similarly,for 3K+1.but 3K+2 is exactly divisible by 3 as u said.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27544/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-justin-takro).

Answer (score 2):

I think a good idea for the problem is using modulos. So, the problem can be written like this
$$
z=4-x^2 \text{ }mod(6),
$$
We know that $100=96+4=4\quad mod(6)$. So $100^2=(100)*(100)=4*4=16=12+4=4\quad mod(6)$. If $z$ is divisible for $6$, then $z=0\quad mod(6)$. For all of this we have to find $x$ such that
$$
x^2=4\quad mod(6).
$$
We have to make a table where we can analize $x^2\quad mod(6)$.

For $x=0$, $x^2=0$ and $x^2=0\quad mod(6)$.

For $x=1$, $x^2=1$ and $x^2=1\quad mod(6)$.

For $x=2$, $x^2=4$ and $x^2=4\quad mod(6)$.

For $x=3$, $x^2=9$ and $x^2=3\quad mod(6)$.

For $x=4$, $x^2=16$ and $x^2=4\quad mod(6)$.

For $x=5$, $x^2=25$ and $x^2=1\quad mod(6)$.

So, the last proposition implies that $x=2 \quad mod(6)$ or $x=4 \quad mod(6)$.

In summary, if $x=2+6m$ or $x=4+6n$ for $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then, $z$ is divisible by $6$. There are infinity solutions.

Comment: Rather than the table, if 6 divides $x^2-4$ then x is even .Let x=2y. So $ 6| (x^2-4)$  iff $ 6|(4y^2-4)$  iff $ 3|(y^2-1) $ iff $ 3|(y-1)(y+1)$ iff $ [3|(y-1)$  or  $3|(y+1)$].